# The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 561015905.)

Tags: ios, swift

I need to play a sound on receiving a push notification in my iOS app while my app in silent mode and killed state.
Below code is not working , returning error **The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 561015905.)**

**NotificationService.swift**

import UserNotifications

import AVFoundation

import MediaPlayer

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

```
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    playSound()
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

}

extension NotificationService {

```
//MARK: - Set up
private func playSound() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        if let url = URL(string: "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9A4FCED-7432FE-FEW-A559-234FBW/Library/Sounds/Update.caf") {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url,  fileTypeHint: AVFileType.caf.rawValue)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { // Give 5 sec delay to play audio or else audio will not hearable
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("[SoundPlayer] There was an error \(error.localizedDescription):")
    }
    
    if (audioPlayer.isPlaying) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

}

Comment: `error` instead or `error.localizedDescription`, it might be more helpful.

Comment: error.localizedDescription returning The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 561015905.) @Larme

Comment: Where does a guy named audioPlayer come from?

Comment: Seems to be https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiotypes/avaudiosessionerrorcode/avaudiosessionerrorcodecannotstartplaying?language=objc according to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/134082 did you allow the audio in background?

Comment: @ElTomato I have changed the code, see please

Comment: @Larme Yes I did.